# Angular <button (click)= not responding

Tags: angular

When I click on the button in nothing happens, no errors. I have the following HTML code:

```
  <body>
        <mat-card>
          <mat-card-content>
            <span class="mat-display">To see buy/sell data for Apple stock click Go</span>
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
              <button (click)="getstock()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Go</button>
          </mat-card-actions>  
      </mat-card>
```

Here is the component code:

```
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor(private api: ApiService){
    }
getstock(){
  this.api.getBuySellData()
}

}
```

and finally the api.service.ts code

```
export class ApiService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

stock: StocksComponent
list: any[]
stockURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stock'
stocksURL = 'https://localhost:44310/api/stocks'

 /** POST: */
postStock (stocks) {
this.http.post(this.stocksURL, stocks).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
} 
getBuySellData() {
  return this.http.get(this.stockURL)
}
getBuySellDatas() {
  return this.http.get(this.stocksURL)
}

}
```

I cannot find the error.

Comment: Since `getBuySellData` returns an Observable, you need to subscribe to it. Otherwise, *nothing* happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not subscribing to the `Observable` returned from `this.http.get()` in your `getBuySellData()` function. Since you want access to it in your `HomeComponent`, you will want to assign a variable to hold the `Observable` and then subscribe to it within that component to get the data.

When you subscribe to the `Observable` the HTTP Request will fire.

The HTTP Request will not be completed unless you subscribe to it like you had done for the POST request in your other method.

It should look similar, like so:

```ts
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor(private api: ApiService){}

    Observable<any> $buySellData;

    getstock() {
        this.$buySellData = this.api.getBuySellData();
        this.$buySellData.subscribe((data: any) => {
            // Use the `data` variable to produce output for the user
        });
    }

}
```

The reason it is beneficial to store the `Observable` instead of subscribing directly to the return value of the `ApiService` call is that you can use Angular's `async` pipe to subscribe to the `Observable` in your template. That would look like this:

```html
<div>{{$buySellData | async}}</div>
```

That way, Angular will take care of unsubscribing for you, and you won't have to store the resolved value(s) of the `Observable` in another variable.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  It totally works.  Much better on what I started with.  I appreciate your expertise.